# Java - Storing image as a Blob in JavaDB

Tags: java, image, jdbc, blob, javadb

I'm trying to insert an image into a database, but getting the following:

java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'BLOB' from a data value of type 'java.io.InputStream(ASCII)'.

I'm using blob in the database.

Here is how I'm doing the insertion:

```
package javaapplication16;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;

public class JavaApplication16 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
            try {
                try {
                    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication16.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication16.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication16.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            CachedRowSet crs = null;
            crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            crs.setUrl("jdbc:derby:derbyDB; create = true");
            crs.setUsername("x");
            crs.setPassword("x");
            crs.setCommand("drop table tbl");
            crs.execute();
            crs.setCommand("CREATE TABLE tbl (ID blob)");
            crs.execute();
            File f = new File("/images/exam_gif_to_png.gif");
            crs.setCommand("insert into tbl (id) values (?)");
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
            crs.setBinaryStream(1, fin, (int) f.length());
            crs.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication16.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

By the way, about storing the path of the image only, the problem is that I want users to be able to send me images and store them in a file, and I'm not sure how exactly to resolve the issue of having multiple images with the same name, will renaming be a good and simple solution?

Comment: Make sure index 5 refers to the right parameter. They are 1 indexed! Also, `available()` returns only an estimate!

Comment: I'm sure about the index

Comment: " will renaming be a good and simple solution?" YOu should store the images with your own naming scheme, and store in the DB the "Original name" along with the pointer to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File f = new File(imagePath);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
crs.setBinaryStream(5, fin, (int) f.length());
```

EDIT --- EDIT

Try this:

I think your problem is that you are not propagating changes.

Call `acceptChanges()` after every command.

```
crs.setCommand("drop table tbl");
crs.execute();
crs.acceptChanges();

crs.setCommand("CREATE TABLE tbl (ID blob)");
crs.execute();
crs.acceptChanges();

crs.setBinaryStream(1, fin, (int) f.length());
crs.execute();
crs.acceptChanges();
```

Comment: Added you mentioned. Got this exception for the line crs.acceptChanges(); done after creating the table: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.initSQLStatements(CachedRowSetWriter.java:1064)
 at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.writeData(CachedRowSetWriter.java:300)
 at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:880)
 at javaapplication16.JavaApplication16.main(JavaApplication16.java:41)
Java Result: 1